# SEO on moving to subdomains because of franchise

Tags: seo, wordpress, web-development

So I own a VR arcade in one location and had www.vr-world.se and had good SEO with it. Now I'm opening a new store I've changed to gbg.vr-world.se and sodra.vr-world.se

I'm just worried this might really effect people finding my original arcade. Any tips to doing this?

I've moved the Rich Cards and stuff to the new gbg.vr-world.se and created new ones for the new shop. The thing is, what will happen to the original www site from an SEO perspective?

I was trying to think what say McDonalds would do, I imagine the main website only has the "Website" rich card, and each of the resturants pages have thier own rich card "LocalBusiness".

Any thoughts on how to keep up my good SEO? (And by good SEO I mean people could find us with really obsure combinations of words relating to VR)

[Google Search For The Arcade](https://www.google.com/search?q=VR+World+Gothenburg)

[Link to our new main website](https://www.vr-world.se/)

Comment: What are you planning to do with redirects?  You should probably redirect every deep page in the site to the correct page on the subdomain for the existing arcade.  You might not want to redirect the old home page, instead you could put up a page there asking users to choose the correct location.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I've done

I you have a look at https://www.vr-world.se/ you'll see it's just a map, and you choose where you want to go

I've moved the entire old site from www. to gbg.

My only concern is that this would somehow bugger up the SEO for the old site